# how to load iframe only with div tag show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have working div show/hide page. Now I would like to add chat box into it. The chat box is embedded in iframe.  Demo here:
https://jsfiddle.net/3uwxsjtb/1/

```
<div>
<a href="#faqbox">
<div>Chat here</div>
</a>
<div id="faqbox">
<pre>Hello 
<!-- How load this iframe only when div show  clicked. -->
<!-- <iframe src="https://hack.chat/?etcj399c" width="50%" height="200" frameborder="0"></iframe> -->

</pre>
<a href="#">Hide</a></div>
</div>
```

css part

```
#faqbox {
    display: none;
}

#faqbox:target {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add your iframe after the click, because with css only the iframe is loaded always.

try this with jQuery:
HTML:

```
<div>
<a href="#faqbox">
<div class="load-iframe">Chat here</div>
</a>
<div id="faqbox">
<pre class="content">Hello 


</pre>
<a href="#" class="hide">Hide</a></div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.load-iframe').click(function(){
         $('.content').append('<div id="iframe"><iframe src="https://hack.chat/?etcj399c" width="50%" height="200" frameborder="0"></iframe></div>');
    });

    $('.hide').click(function(ev){
         ev.preventDefault();
         $(document).find('#iframe').remove();
    });
});
```

[EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/3uwxsjtb/4/)

Comment: thanks a lot, it works now, but creates another issue : whenever you hide and show again the chatbox is getting added. Any thoughts how can i avoid that?

Comment: I have edited the code and the example! Great to help you :)